# How to manage standalone localization for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, lokalise

I have a rails server serving other react and mobile applications.
I have an architectural struggle I would like a suggested way to cope with.
Let's say I maintain a Q&A list that I send the mobile app on demand, this Q&A is stored in the database (in english) and I want to maintain translation of these strings so I can send the clients in other languages as well (such as Arabic).

Furthermore, Although the Q&A are stored in the DB, I do not want to maintain the translations in the DB, so I can let translators be able to insert and correct translations without the need for me to modify the DB, or need to update the app and deploy (so I don't want to need to update any yaml files).

My mobile app uses *lokalise* but it seems to be only relevant for mobile apps, and the keys have to be pre-configured in the app. so this might not be the right approach for me.

Are there any other recommended services, or code solutions to solve this?
I don't mind storing a translation key in the DB along with the added Q&A, but the translation itself needs to be able to be modified from outside my server or codebase.